# Adding query data to url in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, routeparams

I'm working on a SPA with Svelte. I have svelte-spa-router module installed. Nowhere seems to be documentation or examples how to add some object to your url.

This is easy in Vue:

```
router.push({ path: 'pathName', query: { someattribute: 'mygreatvalue' }})
```

In Svelte however the "push" only seems to support "location".
I tried some vanilla function but it adds the data in the wrong place.
My url looks like so:
myniftyspa.com/#/thepage
and I want:

> myniftyspa.com/#/thepage/?someattribute=mygreatvalue

or:

> myniftyspa.com/#/thepage/someattribute/mygreatvalue

it needs to stay on the page without reloading because I just want to store some data in the url this way. In the end it's about storing some ingredients information nested in an object that is being picked up after a revisit.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but have you thought about using a [store](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores) for this?

Comment: I haven't because it was not the point of my question to store on a local computer ;)
The point is being able to share the link or save it as a bookmark or a link on a page.
in other words: using params as they are intended ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured something out as a "solution" that works for now. Maybe it's helping someone with the same issue.

*the object you want to be stored:*

```
   const ingrParams = [
      {
        id: 308,
        gr: 100 
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        gr: 100 
      },
      {
        id: 233,
        gr: 80 
      }
    ];
```

*The snippet:*

```
 push("/ingredients-to-nutrients/" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(ingrParams)));
 let p = JSON.parse(params.paramnameyousetinrouter);
```

(push is an import of the svelte-spa-router module)
note: you need to do an initial push at onMount or else this push will be seen as a page change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla `window.history` to set the current url without reload. Like so:

```js
// address bar shows www.domain.com

window.history.pushState(null, '', window.location + '?foo=bar') 

// address bar shows www.domain.com?foo=bar
```

Comment: thank you, I kind of figured that the days after but this won't work in an SPA with hash notation. That is why router modules exist (among the reason for convenience)